# Reading a Stream object without consuming it

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-rpc

I'm using XML-RPC.NET (from http://www.xml-rpc.net/) and the HttpListener method of listening for XML-RPC communication on a specific network port and responding to it.

The body of a request that comes in is accessible through the `HttpListenerContextInstance.Request.InputStream` Stream object:

```
HttpListener hlListener = new HttpListener();
HttpListenerContext hlcContext = hlListener.GetContext();
// hlcContext.Request.InputStream contains what I want
```

The Stream can be accessed from `hlcContext.Request.InputStream` but this Stream is not seekable so I can't read it/display it and then seek back to the beginning of it so that the XML-RPC.NET library can use it as it needs to. Once it's read, it's consumed and can't be re-read.

I understand that one way of handling this situation would be to convert it from a Stream into a MemoryStream which does support seeking, however, I don't know of a way to do this so that XML-RPC.NET continues on using the MemoryStream instead of the Stream. Just copying the Stream to a MemoryStream seems to consume the Stream making it unusable past that point:

```
// hlcContext.Request.InputStream is currently filled
MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream();
hlcContext.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(msInput);
byte[] byteInput = msInput.ToArray();
// hlcContext.Request.InputStream is now empty and XML-RPC.NET can no longer use it :(
```

How can I read from the Stream so that I can store it in a String and have the Stream continue to work with XML-RPC.NET after that point?

Comment: How are you providing the stream to XML-RPC.NET? I don't see that in your example code.

Comment: The Stream is created by the XML-RPC.NET library somehow/somewhere whenever the website is accessed (http://localhost/DoSomething).

Comment: I haven't got time to look through the code, but assuming `HttpListener` is an XML RPC type, then you might be able to subclass it and change how `GetContext()` is implemented to inject the behaviour you need.

Comment: Change IHttpRequest.InputStream and add a setter.  Fix all the implementations.

Comment: Thanks Hans, this sounds good but I'm somewhat of a novice programmer and am unsure as to the syntax of doing this. Would it be something like: `public class EditableHttpRequest : IHttpRequest
 {
  System.IO.Stream InputStream;

  public System.IO.Stream InputStream { get; set; }

  // Do something here with InputStream
 }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't find a legitimate way, here is a hack to set a stream to `Request.InputStream` (As a last resort)

```
MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream();
hlcContext.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(msInput);
byte[] byteInput = msInput.ToArray();
msInput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

request.GetType().InvokeMember("m_RequestStream", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, request, new object[] { msInput });
```

Now you can freely use `byteInput`

Comment: What is it about this code that makes it a hack/last resort? Will it introduce instability? The application is a critical business app so if this could cause unforeseen problems then it'd be best not to use it.

Comment: @Coder6841, I don't think there would be an instability. By using this code, you access to the private variable (`m_RequestStream`) of `request` object. If MS wanted you to do it, it would mark it as public. This means that it may change in next releases of .Net frameworks(Although I haven't seen any change in the past versions)

Answer (score 0):

This should work with a Stream that supports seeking ([CanSeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek.aspx) == true).

```
MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream();
var preCopyPosition = hlcContext.Request.InputStream.Position;

hlcContext.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(msInput);
byte[] byteInput = msInput.ToArray();

// Go back to pre-copy state
hlcContext.Request.InputStream.Position = preCopyPosition;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Stream does not support seeking. "hlcContext.Request.InputStream.Position = preCopyPosition;" will just give an unsupported exception.

Comment: Ok.  I'll leave this up to prevent a copy.